# The timezone application in django is not working even when I have it configured in the settings

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, timezone

The TIME_ZONE of my application in django is currently not working I have been reading about it and what I currently have in the settings of my application corresponds to what is in the django documentation, the configurations are the following:

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

[image]

Now when I try to use timezone.now() , imported from django.utils import timezone , I get this in the following code

[image]

The output is this

[image]

As you can see, the timezone.now() brings me a completely different time than it should be, and I test that with date_now . I don't understand why if I'm using TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris' in the application settings it doesn't bring me the exact time of the city.

On the other hand a possible solution would be to use this

[image]

But if I use this I would have to change in all parts of my application to put timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) when according to the documentation just using timezone.now() should work

Comment: `timezone.now()` is returning the correct time, it just always returns a UTC datetime. When the datetime is rendered in the front-end it will be converted to localtime so there's really no need to convert it yourself

Comment: Ok, but currently it doesn't send anything to the frontend the dilemma is that there are validations within the application that require the timezone.now() , for example... The user entered the application at this time but how is he taking that time in UTC and not the one in the settings.

Comment: That's fine, Django always deals with times in UTC and `timezone.now()` and `timezone.localtime(timezone.now())` are equal to the same time just with different offsets/timezones

Comment: The problem is that timezone.now() and timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) return different times, currently I have the whole app using timezone.now() and surprise it does not take the time that is in the settings.